# vSphere web client error [400] cannot log in

Tags: webclient, vmware, vsphere

i have a problem with the the vsphere web client when i open it it shows me this error.
"[400] An error occurred while sending an authentication request to the vCenter Single Sign-On server - An error occurred when processing the metadata during vCenter Single Sign-On setup - AFD Native Error Occured: 9127."
i dont understand what is happening can any one explain to me the reason behind this error and how to fix it
thank you

Comment: If you google that error, there's a lot of people pointing to DNS related issues. Example: https://communities.vmware.com/message/2775978?tstart=0#2775978